# Load preferences in another activity?

Tags: android, android-widget, sharedpreferences, textview

I stored a value in my MainActivity called "tgpref".

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
           editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); //value to save
           editor.commit();"
```

In my onCreate i have

```
public SharedPreferences preferences;
---
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I want to display the value in my widget so i try to write in the onUpdate in widget provider class this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false)
        if (tgpref == true) { 
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, "Risp on");
      } else {
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, "Risp off");
      }
```

If the toggle button in the MainActivty is clicked i want that in my widget appears "Risp on" else "Risp off". Right now displays only "Risp off" so i don't know how i can do. Any helps? Nothing happen i can't load the value

Comment: Anyone can help me? I can't load the value in my widget.

Answer (score 0):

it looks good, so i guess your button doesn`t trigger the value change?!

MainActiviy

```
private Boolean mTgpref;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //...
   //get value from shared preferences and update ui
   prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   mTgpref = prefs.getBoolean("tgpref", false);
   setYourText();

}

private void setYourTextAndStoreToSharedPref(){   
    Log.i("TEST","mTgpref -> " + mTgpref); //check value 
    if(mTgpref){        
       remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, "Risp on");
    }
    else
    {
       remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, "Risp off");
    }
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("tgpref", mTgpref).commit();

    //UPDATE YOUR WIDGET HERE
}    

//function called on switch button click    
private void onSwitchClickButtonClick(){
    mTgpref = !mTgpref;   //toggle Boolean
    setYourText();
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, I misunderstood your main problem. After updating SharedPreferences, you should follow the steps described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration

Comment: upps, thought your main problem was with sharedPreferences, i ll edit my answer